# Expression that returns an attribute value from the nearest point from a different layer

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

I have two layers, both with point geometry, both shapefiles, and both representing lamp posts:

- *planned*
- *surveyed*

The *`planned`* Shapefile has a field *`lamp_id`*, type String.

I have added a field with the same name and type to the surveyed layer.

Now I want to automatically modify each feature in *surveyed* so the *`lamp_id`* gets the value ´lamp_id´ from the nearest feature in the *`planned`* layer.

In was hoping to be able to use the Field Calculator tool and writing something like this pseudocode:

```
nearest_point(´planned´).get_field_value('lamp_id')
```

Is this possible? Are there other/better solutions?

I know about running "Join Attributes By Nearest", but I don't want to create a new layer, I want to add the information to the existing layer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
overlay_nearest('planned',"lamp_id")[0]
```

Comment: I have similar question, and this works. However, the code returns the value in brackets, like (attribute value), and I just want attribute value. Do you maybe know how to avoid that, and get the value without brackets? Or is it impossible?

Comment: brackets `[]` are arrays. Use `array_to_string()`, `array_get()`, `array_first()` or similar expressions to turn them into a string, integer or float.

Comment: I don't know, whichever code I use, I get for example: (Mixed Land Use), but I just want to get it without the code, like this: Mixed Land Use.

Comment: Sorry, I dont really understand. Maybe ask it as new question with an example and screenshots.